# How to add emit information to a component dynamically generated using Vue.extent()?

Tags: vue.js, emit

I'm dynamically generating instances of my child component "Action.vue" using `Vue.extent()` this way:

```
let ActionClass = Vue.extend(Action)
let ActionInstance = new ActionClass({
  store
})
ActionInstance.$mount()
this.$refs.actions.appendChild(ActionInstance.$el)
```

This works fine. However, besides access to the store, child component also needs to emit an event (in response to user interaction with one of its elements) for the parent component to execute a method.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439513/how-to-add-emit-information-to-a-component-dynamically-generated-using-vue-exten#comment105062891_59439558) below, you want the parent to be able to set which event the child emits. Can you clarify that in the question?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: You already have the instance.. why not use `ActionInstance.$emit(...)` or `ActionInstance.$store`

Comment: The issue isn't the `$emit` part but the parent's response to it. Normally when calling the child we have `<child-component @customEvent="runThisParentMethod">` so parent runs `runThisParentMethod` when event is emitted. But how to do that in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instance.$on` method to add `eventListeners`dynamically :

> Consumer

```
import Dummy from "./Dummy.vue";
import Vue from "vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    mount: function() {
      const DummyClass = Vue.extend(Dummy);
      const store = { data: "some data" };
      const instance = new DummyClass({ store });
      instance.$mount();
      instance.$on("dummyEvent", e => console.log("dummy get fired", e));
      this.$refs.actions.appendChild(instance.$el);
    }
  }
};
```

> Child component

```
export default {
  methods: {
    fire: function() {
      console.log("fired");
      this.$emit("dummyEvent", { data: "dummyData" });
    }
  }
};
```

Here is the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-kare-slocs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

You can use a lifecylce hook (for example: mounted) to emit the event when the child has been created.
you can listen to the events as documented in the documentation.

the store can be reached through **this.$store**.

Comment: Uh.. But in the parent component you need to specify the event emitted from the child to which the parent can respond. The question is how to specify this in the parent